# Example app.js failed to start, getting GAVE UP Application failed to start on Cloud Foundry

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry

Here's what I did, straight out of http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/nodejs/nodejs.html, making allowances for the outdated documentation:

```
$ vmc push vknodesample01
Instances> app.js

1: node
2: other
Framework> 1   

1: node
2: node06
3: node08
4: other
Runtime> 1

1: 64M
2: 128M
3: 256M
4: 512M
5: 1G
6: 2G
Memory Limit> 1  

Creating vknodesample01... OK

1: vknodesample01.cloudfoundry.com
2: none
URL> vknodesample01.cloudfoundry.com

Updating vknodesample01... OK

Create services for application?> n

Save configuration?> y

Saving to manifest.yml... OK
Uploading vknodesample01... OK
Using manifest file manifest.yml

Starting vknodesample01... OK
Checking vknodesample01... GAVE UP
Application failed to start.

$ cat app.js
$ cat app.js
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://example.com:1337/');
```

example.com is actually one twenty seven dot 0 dot 0 dot 1

I did not include a package.json file since the doc said you don't need it unless you have a server.js

Comment: I then added a package.json and it still gave the same error

Comment: Yes, app.js is the example node server on nodejs.org:

Answer (score 1):

I would take out the loopback address, so it looks like this ...

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337);
```

When you deploy I would also pick 'node08' rather than the 'node' framework option.

Comment: The following also failed: 

`...listen(app.listen(process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000););
`